# Call javascript function error

Tags: javascript, php, html, xss

I have a problem, i have to call a function from a button onclick().

Javascript :

```
function deleteFolder(elemento){
                var form=document.getElementById(elemento);
                var conf=confirm("Sei sicuro di eliminare questa cartella?\nL'eliminazione sara' definitiva");
                if (conf === true)
                    form.submit();
            }
```

This function get a paramater made by php ,the pRoblem is that if this parameter has some space inside, the function is not called ..

**deleteFolder(FolderName)** --> It works
**deleteFolder(Folder Name**) --> of course it doesnt works

From php i just scan directories and put names of them in multiple form with foreach() function.

So the question is : 
1) How from php i can put parameter that works with calling javascript's function with spaces inside?

2) If i have a directory called "Folder's name", it's enough put addslashes in $_POST to bypass XSS? because it cut all next the apostrophe and became :

HTML

```
<button onclick="deleteFolder(Folder)">
```

Thanxs for any suggestions, i can't find anything similar already in this forum.

Comment: You have an identifier with a space in it?

Comment: You have to be like `elemento = "folder name"` Make it a string

Comment: Yes @BoyWithSilverWings you're right ! that was so simple, thanxs man really !! =) I just put in php a &quot; first and next the parameter so it became a string ;))

Comment: Happy to Help @Kiks777

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks i know, i'm working about it too ;) thanxs btw

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are passing a string to the deleteFolder() method. If that is the case, use the following code.

```
<button onclick="deleteFolder('FolderName')">
<button onclick="deleteFolder('Folder Name')">
```

You should use quotes to indicate that you are passing a string to the function. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the actual folder name in a separate attribute say `folder-name` and in the id have incremental numbers, with this being in place following change would be needed in your JavaScript function.

HTML

```
<button folder-name="Folder" onclick="deleteFolder(id)">
```

JavaScript

```
function deleteFolder(elemento){
   var form=document.getElementById(elemento);
   var folderName = form.getAttribute('folder-name');
   // then use the folderName however you want it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanxs to all replies ! =)

I solve it adding `&quot;` (--> " ) in php

first

```
"<button onclick='deleteFolder(".$elem."); return false;'>Elimina</button>"
```

next

```
"<button onclick='deleteFolder(&quot;".$elem."&quot;); return false;'>Elimina</button>"
```

So the parameter became a string and can be passed to the function =)